# Trying to solve $\int \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}\left ( x \frac{1}{x} \right )dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to solve this integral :

$\int \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}\left ( x \frac{1}{x} \right )dx = \int x^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}}\left ( x\frac{1}{x} \right )dx = \int x^{1/8}\left ( x+x^{-1} \right )dx = \int \left ( x^{9/8}+x^{-1/8} \right )dx = \frac{x^{9/8}}{\frac{9}{8}}+\frac{x^{1/8}}{\frac{1}{8}}+C =\frac{8}{9}x^{9/8}+8x^{1/8}+C
$

My answer is correct ?

Comment: Isn't $x\frac{1}{x}=1$ ? Oh I see what you've done there now... that is not really a standard way of writing $x+x^{-1}$, but I like the creative thinking !

Comment: You need to add 1 to 9/8 at the end.  Also check $x^{1/8}x^{-1}$

Comment: Differentiate the last result; it will not be the same as the last integrand.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Any solution ?

Comment: $\int x^k \,dx=\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$ seems to be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice:

- If it is a multiplication:
  $$\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}\left(x\frac{1}{x}\right)=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}\left(1\right)=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}=x^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3}=x^{\frac{1}{8}}=\sqrt[8]{x}$$
- If it is a 'mixed fraction':
  $$x\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x^2+1}{x}\to\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}\left(x\frac{1}{x}\right)=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right)=\sqrt[8]{x^9}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[8]{x^7}}$$

  ---

$$\int\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}\left(x\frac{1}{x}\right)\space\text{d}x=\int x^{\frac{1}{8}}\space\text{d}x=\frac{8\sqrt[8]{x^9}}{9}+\text{C}$$

$$\int\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}\left(x\frac{1}{x}\right)\space\text{d}x=\int \left[\sqrt[8]{x^9}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[8]{x^7}}\right]\space\text{d}x=\frac{8}{17}\sqrt[8]{x}\left(x^2+17\right)+\text{C}$$

Answer (score 0):

How did you get from $(x\frac{1}{x})$ to $(x+x^{-1})$? That should just be 1 which turns it into $\int x^{\frac{1}{8}}dx$ which is then trivial.

Comment: He seems to be interpreting "$x\frac{1}{x}$" as a "mixed fraction", like "$2\frac{1}{2}$" for "two and a half". Perhaps the source of the problem uses this notation in this way, but it seems unlikely.